# Why event trigger correctly just one time in a same element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have build a really simple app of notes, just for practice, i have a **two components** in one view, **one is for form**, and **the other is for list of notes**. The notes listed have **two actions buttons**, one for **edit**, and one for **delete**. When i click in edit button, it **trigger an event to a parent component** with a note selected and then it fill the data variable 'noteEdit' and **pass this data in prop** to a form component to will update.

When i update the note selected, and i try to click again in edit button from the same note, the **event click is trigger but the form is not recived the prop** anymore, i must to **click in edit button from another note listed**, and then its works normaly. Is like cant trigger the event in the same element consecutively.

**in vuex index.js**

```
async editar(context,payload){
  try {
    let response = await axios.put(`/nota/${payload._id}`,payload)
    console.log(response.data.nota)
    context.commit('actualizar',response.data.nota)

    return [true,'Eliminado']
  } catch (error) {
    return [false,error]
  }      
}
```

**in view Notes**

```
<div class="row">
  <formulario :notaEdit="notaEdit"  class="col-md-4"></formulario>
  <lista @nota-edit="notaEdit = $event" class="col-md-8"></lista>
</div>

...

data() {
 return {
   notaEdit: []
 };
},
```

**in list component**

```
<div class="w-50 pl-3">
      <h4>Acciones</h4>
      <b-button block href="#" variant="primary" @click="$emit('nota-edit',nota)">Editar</b-button>
      <b-button block href="#" variant="outline-danger" @click="remove(nota._id)">Eliminar</b-button>
</div>
```

[view of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMpK.png)

[View with 2 components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzUWW.png)

[List component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwy5.png)

[Form component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imCn7.png)

Comment: hey can you posts codes and not images it will be easy to copy and try it ourselves even the images would be nice if you could post it we dont mind scrolling but mind clicking :P

Comment: Please create a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I fix it, it was an error in my logic, thanks anyway.